# How Install the APK signed with your PRODUCTION certificate to a test device?

Tags: android

I'm trying to test google in app purchase system.

- If I download from the app from google play, in app purchase works.
- However if I run the app directly from android studio, I can't because of error code 5 or 0.

I think its because when running through android studio on test device its not signed. how do i do that ?

Comment: Set up an appropriate signing configuration. See https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: You can Upload your app in BETA for testing the app.

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta i cant see logs when i run from google play

Comment: Oh your app is already upload to google play but you are unable to install ? @jos

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign it manually with your production `keystore`:

```
jarsigner -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore "PATH" -storepass KEYSTORE_FILE app-unsigned.apk ALIAS_NAME
```

Then you maybe need to zipalign:

```
zipalign "-v" "4" "PATH TO SIGNED APK" out.apk
```